# python set() membership and hashable objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to store instances of a class in a set, so I could use the set methods to find intersections, etc. My class has a `__hash__()` function, along with an `__eq__` and a `__lt__`, and is decorated with `functools.total_ordering`

When I create two sets, each containing the same two objects, and do a `set_a.difference(set_b)`, I get a result with a single object, and I have no idea why. I was expecting none, or at the least, 2, indicating a complete failure in my understanding of how sets work. But one?

```
for a in set_a:
    print(a, a.__hash__())
for b in set_b:
    print(b, b.__hash__(), b in set_a)


(<foo>, -5267863171333807568)
(<bar>, -8020339072063373731)
(<foo>, -5267863171333807568, False)
(<bar)>, -8020339072063373731, True)
```

Why is the `<foo>` object in `set_b` not considered to be `in` `set_a`? What other properties does an object require in order to be considered a member of a set? And why is `bar` considered to be a part of `set_a`, but not `foo`?

edit: updating with some more info. I figured that simply showing that the two objects' **hash**() results where the same meant that they where indeed the same, so I guess that's where my mistake probably comes from.

```
@total_ordering
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.i == other.i

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.i < other.i

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Thing {}>".format(self.i)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.i)
```

Comment: Are the two foos in `set_a` and `set_b` really equal (`==`) or do they just have the same hash?

Comment: [mcve] please. I can think of a few possible reasons for this output.

Comment: can you give us the code for the hash function? we can't help you with what we can't see

Comment: @schwobaseggl that's a great question - I assumed that as long as the hashes where the same, python would treat them as equal. However yes, the __eq__ function considered them equal, as well as having equal hashes.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the behavior you described. Just pasting the `Thing` class here doesn't make a [mcve]. Also, I've noticed that the 2nd `b` object has an extra parenthesis: `<bar)>`. What's up with that?

Comment: @StefanPochmann My lack of understanding of how sets check for membership lead me to post a much shorter amount of info than I had expected to need. A bunch of the questions in this comments section however have lead down the path a path to the cause.

Comment: @DanielleM. Ok, just saw your answer. I'd say in cases where it's "infeasable" to provide an MCVE, it would be good to say so and say why. I don't get it, btw, "foo" and "bar" aren't floats. So was that output not the actual output? Were "foo" and "bar" really numbers? If so, then seeing that would've helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to some of the questions in the comments- the problem was due to the fact that I had believed that ultimately, the hash function decides if two objects are the same, or not. The `__eq__` also needs to match, which it always did in my tests and attempts to create a minimal example here. 
However, when pulling data from a DB in prod, a certain float was being rounded down, and thus, the `x == y` was failing in prod. Argh.